# Enable Audit log To track Particular SQL Login Activities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three logins "user1","user2" and "user3" in sql. 
I want to enable the audit log only for track the update activities done by "user2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use audit filter as "([server_principal_name]='user1')".

Answer (score 0):

> I want to enable the audit log only for track the update activities done by "user2".

Not sure about Audit and i also don't think you can enable Audit for one user,but you can use Extended events to capture the same.

Try creating a sample audit to see which of these(ntusername,session_ntusername,server principal name) are helpful for you

Create extended events and select batch starting events(any ddl,dml should be a batch) and in next screen ,select below

[image]

and in next screen , you can use predicates to log only events for any username.. you can use like condition,equals to predicate and much more as shown below.. you can also multiple conditions with `AND` and `OR` predicates

[image]

you also can log this file to for later analysis just like Audit